# Copying a list one collection to another collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i have a document in collection **coll1** in this form:

```
{_id: 1, "value" : {"listOfNumbers" : [1,2,3]}}
```

I would like to know, how can I copy this list into an existing list of collection **coll2** using pymongo.

I found this query which will replace the existing list of coll2 with the list [3,2,1]:

```
db.coll2.update({_id:1}, {$set: {'value.listOfNumbers' : [3,2,1]}})
```

The problem is, I don't know how to get the list of coll1.

Also, what would be the easiest way to check if the two lists are the same?

I thank you in advance for your replies and your effort to help.

Answer (score 0):

coll1 for me seems to be a simple dictionary, where it should be easy to get the value of the keyword 'value' via

```
coll1['value']
```

As the entry is another dictionary, you should be able to get the list via

```
coll1['value']['list of numbers']
```

For comparison, it depends on the fact, that lists are only equal in python, if the order and the value of the elements is equal. That should be easy to check with isequal (==).